# Finding consecutive attendance for a series of events

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a `SQL` only solution to an issue related to calculating consecutive event attendance.  The events occur on different days so I cannot use any sequential date method for determining consecutive attendance.  To count consecutive attendance for a single person I would start with the most recent event and work my way back in time.  I would count each event that the person attended and when I hit an event the person did not attend I would stop.   This allows me to have a count of recent consecutive attendance of events.  Currently, all of the data is hosted in `SQL` tables and below is sample schema with data:

```
USERS
ID  UserName    MinutesWatched
--- --------    --------------
1   jdoe        30
2   ssmith      400
3   bbaker      350
4   tduke       285

EVENTS
ID  Name        StartDate
--  ----------- ---------
1   1st Event   07/15/2018
2   2nd Event   07/16/2018
3   3rd Event   07/18/2018
4   4th Event   07/20/2018

ATTENDANCE
ID  User_ID Event_ID
--  ------- --------
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   1   4
5   2   4
6   2   3
7   3   4
8   3   2
9   3   1
10  4   4
11  4   3
12  4   2
```

For an output I am trying to get:

```
OUTPUT
User_ID Consecutive   WatchedMinutes
------- -----------   --------------
1            4            30
2            2            400
3            1            350
4            3            285
```

I have built out `C#` code to do this in an iterative fashion but it is slow when I am dealing with 300,000+ users and hundreds of events.  I would love to see a `SQL` version of this.

Below is the method that calculates top event viewers as requested by Dan. The output is actually just a string that lists the Top X event viewers.

```
public string GetUsersTopWatchedConsecutiveStreams(int topUserCount)
{

    string results = "Top " + topUserCount + " consecutive viewers - ";
    Dictionary<ChatUser, int> userinfo = new Dictionary<ChatUser, int>();

    using (StorageModelContext db = new StorageModelContext())
    {
        IQueryable<ChatUser> allUsers = null;
        if (mainViewModel.CurrentStream != null)
            allUsers = db.ViewerHistory.Include("Stream").Include("User").Where(x => x.Stream.Id == mainViewModel.CurrentStream.Id).Select(x => x.User);
        else
            allUsers = db.ViewerHistory.Include("Stream").Include("User").Where(x => x.Stream.Id == (db.StreamHistory.OrderByDescending(s => s.StreamEnd).FirstOrDefault().Id)).Select(x => x.User);


        foreach (var u in allUsers)
        {
            int totalStreams = 0;
            var user = db.Users.Include("History").Where(x => x.UserName == u.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                var streams = user.History;
                if (streams != null)
                {
                    var allStreams = db.StreamHistory.OrderByDescending(x => x.StreamStart);
                    foreach (var s in allStreams)
                    {
                        var vs = streams.Where(x => x.Stream == s);
                        if (vs.Count() > 0)
                            totalStreams++;
                        else
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            userinfo.Add(u, totalStreams);
            totalStreams = 0;
        }

        var top = userinfo.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ThenByDescending(x => x.Key.MinutesWatched).Take(topUserCount);
        int cnt = 1;
        foreach (var t in top)
        {
            results += "#" + cnt + ": " + t.Key + "(" + t.Value.ToString() + "), ";
            cnt++;
        }
        if (cnt > 1)
            results = results.Substring(0, results.Length - 2);

    }
    return results;
}
```

mainViewModel.CurrentStream is null when no event is actively running.  When a live event is occurring it will contain an object with information related to the live stream event.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: "*I have built out C# code to do this*" It must be in transparent ink because I don't see it.

Comment: Gordon - done.  Thanks

Comment: Dan - I didn't originally include the code because I didn't think it would add much value.  I have updated the post with the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to give this one a try:

Events get a row number in descending order (by `StartDate`), also the attendances by user get a number in descending `StartDate` order. Now, the differences of the event numbers and the attendance numbers will be the same for consecutive attendances. I use these differences for grouping, count the attendances in the group and return the group with the lowest difference (by user):

```
WITH
  evt (ID, StartDate, evt_no) AS (
    SELECT ID, StartDate,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDate DESC)
    FROM EVENTS
  ),
  att ([User_ID], grp_no) AS (
    SELECT [User_ID], evt_no - 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User_ID] ORDER BY StartDate DESC)
    FROM ATTENDANCE a
      INNER JOIN evt ON a.Event_ID = evt.ID
  ),
  con ([User_ID], Consecutive, rn) AS (
    SELECT [User_ID], COUNT(*),
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY grp_no)
    FROM att
    GROUP BY [User_ID], grp_no
  )
SELECT u.ID AS [User_ID], u.UserName, u.MinutesWatched, con.Consecutive
FROM con
  INNER JOIN USERS u ON con.[User_ID] = u.ID
WHERE con.rn = 1;
```

Would be interested in how long this query runs on your system.

Comment: Initial test looks very promising. I need to look the results over closely and double checking everything.  From a speed perspective it is scary fast... about 1 sec (or less).

Comment: Looks like this is it!  I am still trying to wrap my head around how this all works.  SQL is one of those things that causes my head to spin sometimes.  LOL.  Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Thank you, great to hear that! :-) The trick is that with "consecutive" attendances, the numberings of attendances and events both increment one by one. When one or more events are missed, the event number has increased more than the attendance number.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the largest event id that a person did not attend, which is smaller than the largest id the person did attend.  Then you want to count the number the person attended.

The following approach handles this as:

- Combine the users with all events up to the maximum event
- Get the largest event that *doesn't* match
- Bring back the rows where the count is 0 and count them

So, this gives the events with the count:

```
select u.user_id,
       sum(case when a.event_id is null then e.id end) over (partition by user_id) as max_nonmatch_event_id
from (select user_id, max(event_id) as max_event_id
      from attendance 
      group by user_id
     ) u join
     events e
     on e.id <= u.max_event_id left join
     attendance a
     on a.user_id = u.id and a.event_id = e.id
order by num_nulls_gt;
```

One more subquery should do the rest:

```
select u.user_id, count(*) as num_consecutive
from (select u.user_id,
       sum(case when a.event_id is null then e.id end) over (partition by user_id) as max_nonmatch_event_id
      from (select user_id, max(event_id) as max_event_id
            from attendance 
            group by user_id
           ) u join
           events e
           on e.id <= u.max_event_id left join
           attendance a
           on a.user_id = u.id and a.event_id = e.id
     ) ue
where event_id > max_nonmatch_event_id
group by user_id;
```

Comment: After digging deeper into the results I am seeing some issues where a users is showing a very high consecutive view count even though they had only seen the most recent event.   I am not sure what is causing the issue yet, looking deeper into the dataset.   It also appears that the first select should be  select ue.user_id and not u.user_id,  correct?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to meet the requriements.  I have spent a bit of time disecting what you did and I don't see how this would give me the count of consecutive views.   If a users has attended all 4 of the past events I would expect to get a 4 back.  If a users attended the first event, missed the 2nd event, and then attended for the 3rd and 4th event, I would expect to get a 2 back from the query for that user.